# OCaml - Need some help at implementing my rev function

Tags: ocaml, reverse

I've got an assignment where I have to recode a big part of the different functions found on "list". I'm currently having trouble implementing the rev function.

```
type 'a my_list =
     | Item of ('a * 'a my_list)
     | Empty;;
```

This is the type of lists we are allowed to use and here is my attempt at doing it:

```
let rev my_list =
    let rec rev_list list = function
        | Empty               -> list
        | Item (first, rest) -> rev_list (Item (first, list)) 
          rest in rev_list Empty;;
```

rev function has for prototype:

```
'a list -> 'a list:
```

and this is what I'm getting:

```
'a -> 'b my_list -> 'b my_list
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Well, right as I posted the question I found the answer, if it might help anybody, here it is

```
let rev my_list =
let rec rev_list list = function
| Empty               -> list
| Item (first, rest) -> rev_list (Item (first, list))
rest in rev_list Empty my_list
```